# JavaScript this scope in callback functions

Tags: javascript

How can I access object properties from functions which will be called as callback function. Please see code below. How can I access config property from processData function which will called when data is received from the server in ajax call.

```
MyClass: {
    config: {
        name: "",
        id: ""
    },

    loadData: function() {
        MyApi.getData(
            this.config,
            this.processData,   //sucess
            this.failureHandler //failure
        );
    },

    processData: function() {
        // how to access config object here? 
    }
}
```

Probably you can create an anonymous handler function and use call or apply to pass the this scope to actual handler function but is there a better solution than that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserve 'this' reference in javascript prototype event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100469/preserve-this-reference-in-javascript-prototype-event-handler)

Comment: `this.processData.bind(this)` is you don't want anonymous function.

Comment: Where is MyApi declared?

Comment: MyApi is another object written in a separate file: MyApp. MyApi with namespace. Think of it as a wrapper around $.ajax