# Accessing instance variables from other functions

Tags: javascript, class

I can't access a JavaScript variable from another function that has been instantiated in the constructor function. It returns `undefined`.

I am instantiating a new object of the class `Box`, and in the constructor function, defining instance variables, creating HTML elements and setting up an event listener. The handler for this listener, `clickHandler`, is a function that is defined on the prototype. From `clickHandler`, I am trying to access the `this.selected` variable. But I get `undefined`.

The code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  

<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="element1"></div>
<br/>
<div id="element2"></div>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script>
    init([{id: "element1"}, {id: "element2"}]); //call init function
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript** script.js

```
function Box(id, count) { //the class
    this.selected = false; //need this variable in clickHandler
    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.id = "container" + count;
    this.div.style.width = "250px";
    this.div.style.height = "150px";
    this.div.style.border = "1px solid black";
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(this.div);
    this.div.addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler, false); //add event listener on the created div element
}

Box.prototype.clickHandler = function() { //click handler
    console.log("clickHandler, selected = " + this.selected); // undefined
};

function init(settings) {
    //var obj;
    for(var i = 0; i < settings.length; i++) {
        new Box(settings[i].id, (i+1)); //instantiate new object
    }
}
```

How can I access the `this.selected` variable in various event handler functions? I plan to listen for multiple events and need the `this.selected` variable for that. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100469/preserve-this-reference-in-javascript-prototype-event-handler and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 0):

Change adding the handler to:

```
this.div.addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler.bind(this), false);
```

This will bind the object as "this" context in the callback function.

```js
function Box(id, count) { //the class
    this.selected = false; //need this variable in clickHandler
    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.id = "container" + count;
    this.div.style.width = "250px";
    this.div.style.height = "150px";
    this.div.style.border = "1px solid black";
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(this.div);
    this.div.addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler.bind(this), false);
}

Box.prototype.clickHandler = function() { //click handler
    console.log("clickHandler, selected = " + this.selected); // undefined
};

function init(settings) {
    //var obj;
    for(var i = 0; i < settings.length; i++) {
        new Box(settings[i].id, (i+1)); //instantiate new object
    }
}
    init([{id: "element1"}, {id: "element2"}]); //call init function
```

```html
<div id="element1"></div>
<br/>
<div id="element2"></div>
```